# How can I put a image using a div with React?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to put a image in the background in a div but it does not work. Here is my code :

```
<div
                    style='background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1426604966848-d7adac402bff?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8bmF0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60")'
                    className="h-52 sm:h-full sm:w-72 rounded-xl bg-gray-100 bg-center bg-cover"
                ></div>
```

Pycharm told me `XML tag has empty body` because I have nothing between the div tag but I just want to display a image from unsplash ...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Would it help to self-close the tag? `<div style="..." className="..." />`

Comment: The error you should be seeing is: "The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, `style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}}` when using JSX."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below snippet, make sure the path to image is correct.

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: "url(/exampleImage.png)" }}>
  Hello World
</div>
```

Or

```
 <div style={{ backgroundImage: "url(/exampleImage.png)" }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "style={{ backgroud: "url('...')"}}" for put this in React.
And you add a height in you style / class.

```
<div style={{
    background: "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1426604966848-d7adac402bff?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8bmF0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60')",
    height: '50vh'
}}>
</div>
```